# What's the best way to bind ES6 class's "this" to an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to separate class methods into their own files. For example if I have a simple class like this in `test.js`:

```
export default class TestClass {

    testFunction(...args) {
        return require('./test-function').apply(this, args);
    }

}
```

And then in `test-function.js` method:

```
export default function() {
    /* `this` keyword works fine */
}
```

However, if I change it to an arrow function, then **this** does not work anymore (because of lexical scoping?):

```
export default () => {
    /* `this` doesn't work anymore */
}
```

How would I bind `this` properly so my arrow `test` function can use it?

Comment: Please see [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196) as well.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr - you cannot.

If you export an arrow function, that function will have it's lexical `this` bound to either the global object (non-strict mode) or it will be undefined (strict mode).

That's how arrow functions are supposed to work. If you need the function to get your class object's `this`, you **must** use standard `function () {}` body.